# jQuery: question about inArray()

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this code below. I don't know why inArray() doesn't output 0. Any idea?

```
var client = new Array();

function removeClient(id){

  alert(id);    //prints 17
  alert(client);   //prints 17
  alert(typeof(id));  //this prints "number"
  alert(typeof(client));  //this prints "object"
  alert($.inArray(id, client));   //this prints "-1", why?

}
```

Regards

Javi

Comment: How do you populate the array?

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/PFU9x/

Comment: Or here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ub6xX/

Comment: I'm populating the array using push(). If I add more elements the elements are separated with the comma in the output. I'm populating this way "client.push(data[1]);"

Comment: If client contained the string `"17"` and not the number `17` this would happen.

Comment: @user248959: Then `data[1]` is probably a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably populated the array with the string `'17'` and not the number `17`. That's why it returns `-1`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/s4Q3K/

Comment: @Felix Good riddle though `:)`

Answer (score 3):

[`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns -1 when an element is not found.  <strike>Can we see where you are filling client with array values?  You might not be filling the array correctly.</strike>

<strike>`alert(client)` should not print '17' it should print the array values separated by commas.</strike>

**EDIT**: I figured out what may the the issue.  If `client` contains the string `'17'` and not the number `17`, because `17 !== '17'`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ub6xX/1/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ub6xX/

Comment: If the array only contains one value, 17, the output it indeed only 17.

Comment: @Felix: I... knew that.  I need more coffee.

Answer (score 2):

Because `inArray(id, client)` checks whether `id` is in the array `client`.

And since `id` is not in that array (at least not per your sample), it returns `-1`. [Know your API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: @Tomalak "id is not that array"? You mean "id is not *in* that array"?

Comment: @Tomalak If `id` (which is the number 17) is not in the array `client` then why does `client` print to `'17'`?

Comment: @Šime Of course. Fixed, thanks. I suppose that `client` is not actually an array in the OP's real code. It is in the sample, though. (If it *was* an array, it would print `[17]`, and the sample would work.)

Comment: @Tomalak: It never prints the square brackets if you alert an array.

Comment: @Felix: Whoops, that's right. I was thinking `console.log()`. Nevertheless, it prints `-1` because either `client` is not actually an array or it does not contain `17`. It's a simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

-1 means not found, so basically the id does not exist in the items of the array.

0 would mean that it had found the id at the first position of the array. Nothing in your code suggests that this should happen.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: `alert(client);` indicates that the array contains one element.

Answer (score 0):

> The $.inArray() method is similar to
>   JavaScript's native .indexOf() method
>   in that it returns -1 when it doesn't
>   find a match. If the first element
>   within the array matches value,
>   $.inArray() returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely
>   equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0
>   !== false), if we're checking for the
>   presence of value within array, we
>   need to check if it's not equal to (or
>   greater than) -1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you you are putting the id into the client array in your exmaple I'm guessing because you don't have it in there in array can't find it